# Will AWS work with Spring Boot and React?

Tags: spring, reactjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying out local development with Spring Boot and React where I run `mvn spring-boot:run` (this runs on http://localhost:8080) for the Spring server, then I run `npm start` (this runs on http://localhost:3000) for the React client. My knowledge is that React is the front facing component that clients will talk to and then Spring will be what React interacts with for back-end operations.

Will a setup like this work similarly in a AWS setup like AWS Elastic Beanstalk? I am confused because most of what I read up involves passing the .jar or .war to AWS to run Spring but how would a setup work for when React is the front facing component?

-Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could deploy your Spring Boot Uber Jar to AWS Beanstalk then run an npm build to create your React bundled application and deploy that to AWS S3. You will need to change some app settings to point to the correct (Beanstalk) server and make sure your AWS S3 settings are correct. There are examples within AWS documentation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I ended up needing the right setup in the maven and npm builds... following loosely on this: http://matejsprogblog.blogspot.ca/2017/06/creating-new-web-app-using-create-react.html. Main points being that I need to build both and then copy over the client to the maven target, resulting in a packaged jar file.

Comment: @craigwor: what are these correct settings that you can use to point to the correct beanstalk?